# Aligning text according to user input in python

Tags: python

```
aStr = input("Enter a string message: ")
fW = eval(input("Enter a positive integer: "))
print(f"Right aligned is <{aStr:>fW}>")
```

so, this is my code, I would like to align the spaces according to the user input. Whenever I try to use eval or int in fW, it shows this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vmabr\Downloads\A1Q2.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(f"Right aligned is <{aStr:fW}>")
ValueError: Invalid format specifier
```

May I know what's the fix?

Comment: try:
`aStr = input("Enter a string message: ")
fW = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))
print(f"Right aligned is <{aStr.rjust(fW)}>")`

Comment: Before you learn anything else, you should unlearn that the `eval` function exists. `eval` is not safe to use, _especially_ on unsanitized user input as you have done. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/843953

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. My professor was the one who recommended me to use eval so I just followed. Thank you very much for letting me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close. To implement a "parameterized" format-string, you need to wrap the parameter `fW` into additional curly braces:

```py
aStr = input("Enter a string message: ")
fW = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))
print(f"Right aligned is <{aStr:>{fW}}>")  # {fW} instead of fW
```

See [PEP 498 -> format specifiers](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/#format-specifiers) for further information.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works like magic! Curse these curly brackets . . .
Oh and also thanks for the link, I will definitely check it out.